# Nginx permanent redirection with and without trailing slash

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I couldn't find any ways to make url redirection with and without trailing slash to work.

I want to make it whenever url calling to `example.com/info` and `example.com/info/` will go to `example.com/info-page/` with addition of "-page" string at behind of url.

```
location /info/ {
     rewrite ^(/info)(.*)$ http://example.com/$1-page/ permanent;
}
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `location`, just use:

```
rewrite ^/info/?$ http://$host/info-page/ permanent;
```

or

```
if ($request_uri !~ "^/info/?$")
{
  return 301 http://$host/info-page/;
}
```